# Is LC_COLLATE different from COLLATE?

Tags: postgresql, collation

Postgres 12 on Windows 7

This works:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE "foo"
    ENCODING 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en-US'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en-US'
    TEMPLATE template0
```

Afterwards, running `SHOW LC_COLLATE` with database `foo` selected reports:

[image: screenshot]

But when running

```sql
SELECT UPPER('kedi' COLLATE "en-US")
```

it reports:

```
ERROR: collation "en-US" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
```

Shouldn't both accept the same collation names?

Comment: I don't have a Windows system - do you have that name in `pg_collation`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Oh, that's where I find available collations? It's different from finding available locales.  I have (in `pg_collation.collname`) `default`, `C`, `POSIX` and then a whole bunch of language specific ones, for example `en-US-u-va-posix-x-icu` and `en-US-x-icu`.

Comment: Indeed for example `UPPER('kedi' COLLATE "tr-TR-x-icu")` works and yields the expected result (uppercasing using Turkish rules). So, how does Postgres choose a collation (`en-US-u-va-posix-x-icu` or `en-US-x-icu`) if I set LC_COLLATE to e.g. `en-US`?

Comment: It will use neither of these. By default, it always uses a collation from the C library. There are probably some collations named `English` or similar in `pg_collation`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `SELECT array_agg(collname) FROM pg_collation WHERE collname NOT LIKE '%-x-icu'` -> `{default,C,POSIX,ucs_basic}`

Answer (score 3):

`LC_COLLATE` refers to a name of locale from the operating system, whereas `COLLATE` refers to a collation that should exist in `pg_catalog.pg_collation`.

`pg_catalog.pg_collation` is originally populated in the template databases when the PostgreSQL instance is created (by `initdb`).

Specifically it's the SQL function `pg_import_system_collations()` that should do that. From the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) (emphasis mine)

> pg_import_system_collations ( schema regnamespace ) → integer

> Adds collations to the system catalog pg_collation based on all the
> locales it finds in the operating system. This is what initdb uses;
> see Section 23.2.2 for more details. **If additional locales are
> installed into the operating system later on, this function can be run
> again to add collations for the new locales**. Locales that match
> existing entries in pg_collation will be skipped. (But collation
> objects based on locales that are no longer present in the operating
> system are not removed by this function.) The schema parameter would
> typically be pg_catalog, but that is not a requirement; the collations
> could be installed into some other schema as well. The function
> returns the number of new collation objects it created.

For some reason you don't have `en-US` in pg_collation while it's valid from your operating system, so you seem to be in the case where the advice is to run
`pg_import_system_collations()` manually in the databases that need it.

Comment: If the thing in `LC_COLLATE` is not actually a collation, then which collation is used by default when I for example run`LOWER()` ?

Comment: I ran `pg_import_system_collations()` and it returned 0. The contents of `pg_collation` is unchanged.

Comment: @AndreKR: it implies that when PG asks Windows 7 the list of its locales, it doesn't list `en-US`, but when PG ask to use `en-US` as the locale, it seems to say "no problem". So a large part of the explanation is in Windows 7 (which has been EOL'ed last year BTW).